# Remove Channels Via Roku.com

Tags: video-streaming

In addition to adding channels via your Roku device, Roku also allows you to add channels by logging into your account on their [website](https://my.roku.com/). I like this, because you can add channels to all of your devices at once instead of adding the channel on each device individually.

However, on their website, I see no way to delete channels from all devices. I'm trying to:

1. List All Channels I've Already Installed
2. Remove Channels I no longer want (from all devices at once).

Is this possible to accomplish via their Website? Also, I didn't have enough points to tag this with `roku` as a label. If you do, please add that tag to my question.

Comment: This [support article](https://support.roku.com/article/232010488) discusses the removal of channels from the Roku Store, but the instructions are via device instead of via their website.

Comment: This [same question](https://community.roku.com/t5/Channel-Issues-Questions/Remove-Channels-Via-Roku-com/m-p/813130#M120650) has been posted to Roku's community support page.